# UIPicker with dynamic Content Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a table view with a button. The table view also contains a quantity figure like this:

```
Class      Price      Qty     Action
Regular    $5         10       Buy
```

When the buy action is clicked, I'd like to show a uipickerview with number from 1-10 as the content of the picker so the use can select how many tickets they'd like to buy. My problem is that with the normal UIPicker, I'd have to conform to the delegate and set the data source but the data source is dependent on the table view clicked. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Show. Us. Your. Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to create an array that changes its content according to the clicked button then reload the picker, the datasource of the picker is changeable not static as you might think, so implement these methods and change `contentsArr` every button click you want to show data.

```
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return contentsArr.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return contentsArr[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    }
```

Comment: Hi there. As per a couple of my other edits, please avoid txtspk and slang here - Stack Overflow is not a forum or a chatroom.

Comment: Ok , thanks but if i may ask is that a moderator's work ? , i mean why you have to ?

Comment: Mostly, Stack Overflow is [community moderated](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=stack+overflow+community+moderation&t=lm&ia=web). That means, for the most part, the community improves itself, by setting an example for new users, by editing content, by downvoting poor content or lack of effort, by upvoting good content or impressive effort, etc. [Diamond moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) are mostly elected from the community, and they are the 'overseers' when ordinary members have a difficulty they cannot work out.

Comment: Diamond moderators may edit posts if they wish (and they frequently do) but they have a lot of other responsibilities, so probably do not have time to dedicate to a lot of editing. You can see [the busiest editors here](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors), and not many of them are moderators proper.

Comment: So, as an ordinary community member, I don't _have_ to do anything, but I like to edit posts because my English writing is pretty good, and I like to give back to a community that has helped me a lot professionally. The standard of technical communication on Stack Overflow is generally quite poor, so if I can improve it a bit for the benefit of future readers, that's satisfying for me.